# Node.js stream difficulties

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Edited: This is the form code I am using currently.  I basically took it
   from suggestions on stack overflow.

```
    app.post('/FunFun.js', function(req, res) {
    var file = req.params.value; 
console.warn(req.params);
console.warn(req.params.value);
    var fileContent = JSON.stringify(file);


    fs.appendFile('Focus.txt', fileContent + '\n', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Failed to append to the file! ', err)
    } else {
        console.log('Appended data to file!');
    }
    res.render('Form.html');

     });
     });
```

So, I am trying to basically read form values from a survey(multiple choice) I created with HTML into a Stream in my Node.js file in order to save the values of each participant in a txt file( I know a database is preferable, this is for college).  So here is my Node.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var engines = require('consolidate');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/Desktop');
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.get('/', function(reg, res) {
    res.render('Form.html');
});

app.post('/FunFun.js', function(req, res) {
    res.render('Form.html');
    var file = req.body; //req.params.values;
    filecontent = JSON.stringify(file);

    var stream = fs.createWriteStream("Focus.txt", {
        objectMode: true
    }); //{'flags': 'a'});
    stream.on('open', function() {
        stream.write(filecontent);
        stream.end();
    });
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Server listening on port 8080');
});
```

I would post my form, but it is a standard multiple choice questionnaire type form with radio buttons.  Anyways, I want to save the users choice in a file, and to me it seems that my NOde.js file should do the trick, but I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk
```

So I know that streams apparently cannot usually handle data other than strings and buffers.  However, I thought JSON.stringify would do the trick.   However, it isn't.  I am new to Node.js and express, so wondering if anyone has any ideas on what I am missing?

Xtra:  Decided to show a sample of my HTML form just for emphasis.   I am trying to extract the value of the radio button selected.

```
   <form  action = "/FunFun.js" method = "post" style = "border : 2px   
    solid black;">
 .......

<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">7</td>
        <td colspan="8">If I had more time, I would have done better in this course.</td>
        <td colspan="16">
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="g1" name="GroupG" onclick="groupG()" type="radio" value="1std"></td>
                    <td><input id="g2" name="GroupG" onclick="groupG()" type="radio" value="1sod"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td><input id="g3" name="GroupG" onclick="groupG()" type="radio" value="1neu"></td>
        <td colspan="16">
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="g4" name="GroupG" onclick="groupG()" type="radio" value="1sta"></td>
                    <td><input id="g5" name="GroupG" onclick="groupG()" type="radio" value="1soa"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

.....
<td colspan = 100%> <input type="submit" value="submit" formaction 
  = "/FunFun.js"> <input type="reset" onClick = "resetB()">   </td>

</tr>


</table>
```

Comment: "I know a database is preferable, this is for college"  What a hassle.  You're learning the wrong way to do something, and it's going to take you a ton of extra effort to do it.  At least use SQLite3 or something.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the documentation for [`fs.createWriteStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options), you'll see that there is no `objectMode` in the valid options. `objectMode` is not documented, because even though the underlying `stream.Writable` class does support the feature, the `fs.WriteStream` does not. For a good reason - how would it choose how to *serialize* the objects you've given it? How should it represent `{ a:1 }`? In textual JSON? In some binary format? Exactly. That's up to the programmer to choose.

Additionally, the POST handler is writing a response to the client (in HTML) before actually appending to the file (`res.render(...)`). I would suggest moving this to the success callback of the write, so that you actually do the operation before returning results.

So, remove the `objectMode` from the options and move the `res.render(...)` and the write works. Remember that when working with streams which do not operate in object mode, you can only write [strings, `Buffer`s or `Uint8Array`s](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback), so you're correct in using `JSON.stringify` first.

By the way, unless you're streaming directly from the client to the file, which would probably require you to stream the JSON transform on the fly somehow, you'd probably be better off using [`fs.appendFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_file_data_options_callback) or `fs.writeFile`. They have a simpler API which I think you might want:

```
app.post('/FunFun.js', function(req, res) {
    var file = req.body; // req.params.values;
    var fileContent = JSON.stringify(file);

    fs.appendFile('Focus.json', fileContent + '\n', function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed to append to the file! ', err)
        } else {
            console.log('Appended data to file!');

        }
        res.render('Form.html')
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and feedback, I understand what your saying.  However, this still is not working for me, not sure why.  At best, I create an empty file.

Comment: @JPho Looks like I missed a line. I've edited my answer. Move the `res.render(...)` to _after_ you write the file (into the callback). Be aware that if you `writeFile` truncates (empties) the file before writing, `appendFile` adds to the existing file. Also notice that if someone POSTs to the route while the file is being written, you might have a bad time when two appends happen at once.

Comment: Also verify that the `req.body` actually has anything - place a breakpoint and debug it or place a `console.log(fileContent)`.

Comment: I did try your suggestions, and they make sense reading it over, but I still keep getting the same error.... In addition, console.log() is not even working so I cannot see if req.body or req.params has anything in it ( I assumed a value was in it up until now).  Then I read that node.js does not suppert console.log, so how do I determine what is in req.body?? Thanks again tho

Comment: @JPho Node very much does support [`console`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html). It will print not to the browser but to the shell from which you run node. If you're using an IDE, it probably has an Output window. I'm beginning to suspect your POST never makes it to the server. Please add a minimal version of your form or fetch or whatever sends the request to your question.

Comment: Sure, no problem.   So here is the beginning and end of my form code.  As you can see, I use the post method as I researched, and the action value is the path to my Node.js file "/FunFun.js".

Comment: Just to be clear, I only edited my little sample of table html to show the beginning and end of the form, with the formaction method's and value method's values.  Each row is basically identical to the html code inbetween the ellipsis.

Comment: I just assumed that when the method = "post", that means that for form data such as radio button values, the values get saved in req.params or req.body, and then can be written into a database or a txt file.

Comment: if you are able to provide any more clues, much appreciated!

Comment: @JPho An isolated example based on your sample works for me. Perhaps your POST handler is different than my example? Could you add that to the end of your question? Did you see the data being written to the console?

Comment: Sure, that is no problem.  And I did not see any data being written to the console sadly.   So really nothing is working as it should apparently.  But I placed the post handler I currently have at the end of my question for you to see.  Thank you

Comment: Sorry, meant I placed it at the top of my original FunFun.js file above.

Comment: I am really just using some of the ideas you suggested.  Thank you

Comment: Sorry to be annoying but I still have not found an answer to my little problem....anyone out there still have any ideas??  I will keep trying of course